# Read message from DB before throwing an exception on a Reactor switchIfEmpty

Tags: generics, spring-webflux, project-reactor

We are using webflux and I need to throw an error when an object is not found.

We have an error code **ENTITY_NOT_FOUND** and we need to throw a **MyException()** with the message for the error code , that we need to read from DB
The repository is a ReactiveCrudRepository. So it returns a Mono, which we process via map() and populate or translate, then return a Mono , which is final form of the error message.
From the switchIfEmpty step, We try to throw a MyException that we create with this error message

```
Mono.just(new MyEntity())
switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new MyException())
.flatMap(...)
```

the code block above works

```
private Mono<MyException> generateException(){...}

Mono.just(new MyEntity())
switchIfEmpty(generateException())
.flatMap(...)
```

for the code block above, switchIfEmpty complains as below

```
Required type: Mono<? extends MyEntity>
Provided:      Mono<MyException>
```

It's really troublesome to have both JPA and Reactive repositories in a project. So I'm trying to get this done via Reactive repositories

Comment: So the `generateException` is incorrect, because you don't return it, but you throw. It's not a correct type, as the compiler tries to tell you. Correct type is `MyEntity`

Comment: "generateException type is incorrect"

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor generateException() to:

```java
    private Mono<MyEntity> generateException() {
      return Mono.error(new MyException());
    }
```